# DS3231 RTC resets when the power is turned off

Tags: linux-device-driver

In my case I want to connect a ds3231 RTC device to the I2C bus on the Beagle-bone black. Wrote a ds3231 rtc device driver code using device tree overlay and I have been successful in communicating with the chip by instantiating the device tree overlay as follows : **echo BBB-I2C2 > slots** (/sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/). I have followed this link  **https://saintgimp.org/2017/11/05/add-a-real-time-clock-to-a-beaglebone-black/** and my rtc is working properly whenever it is powered on but if **I unplug my rtc device and connect it back then its getting reset .**

[image]

Comment: Do you have a battery  providing power to the RTC while it is unplugged?

Comment: No I have removed all the setup

Comment: Then there is no way the RTC can keep track of the time...

Comment: As I know ds3231 RTC is Battery-Backup Input for Continuous Timekeeping. I didn't remove battery from the RTC . I had just removed connection between RTC from beaglebone black.

Comment: Yes, and the question is whether you have a battery providing power on Vbat. The DS3231 doesn't have an on-chip battery.

Comment: No, but for every boot of beagle-bone black the time of RTC is getting reset. Is it compulsory that I need to connect beagle-bone black to internet to fetch the accurate time. If yes then can you suggest about it.

Comment: Configure one of plenty NTP clients. Or connect battery.

Comment: Ds3231 RTC consists of battery so I am trying without internet connection with beagle-bone black.